# file downloaded from Firebase storage get stored?

Tags: java, android, firebase

I manually uploaded a pdf file to Firebase Storage . Now, I downloaded that file from my app using the method 'Download to a local file' as mentioned in the Firebase Storage documentation, but I am not able to find the downloaded file 
Where can i find my downloaded file i am getting "Download Success"
if any changes need to be done in code plz let me know

```
t3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        //Upload
          //
            //Download
            File localFile = null;
            try {
                localFile = File.createTempFile("file", "pdf");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "directory_name");

            if(!storagePath.exists()) {
                storagePath.mkdirs();
            }

            final File myFile = new File(storagePath,"IBM2013507.pdf");

            StorageReference riversRef = mStorageRef.child("IBM2013507.pdf");


            riversRef.getFile(myFile)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            // Successfully downloaded data to local file
                        Log.v("Download","Success");
                            // ...taskSnapshot
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                    // Handle failed download
                    Log.v("Download","unSuccess");
                    // ...
                }
            });
            //

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the download location in your code:

```
File storagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "directory_name");
final File myFile = new File(storagePath,"IBM2013507.pdf");
```

Since you're downloading to `myFile`, you can expect the find the file on the device's external storage directory in the "directory_name" folder with the file name "IBM2013507.pdf".

If you don't know where that is, try printing the value of `myFile` to see the full path.