# How to get local file path of image file downloaded from Firebase Storage in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-storage

In my React Native app, i need to

1. Upload an image to Firebase Storage
2. Then Download it and edit it (crop/rotate)
3. Upload the edited image the Firebase Storage again

I was able to upload the image, get its URL using the getDownloadURL() method, and display it using `Image` component as it takes the url input right away.

Now I need the local file path in order to edit and reupload the edited image to Firebase Storage.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45085779/how-to-get-the-local-path-from-a-file-downloaded-from-firebase-storage) explains a `getFile()` method, but I cant find it [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference).
Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43043781/file-downloaded-from-firebase-storage-get-stored) give some direction but its in JAVA.

[Some Blogs](https://aboutreact.com/download-image-in-react-native/) mention using libraries such as `react-native-fs`, `react-native-fetch-blob` etc, but it appears they are trying to save the file in storage/gallery. That is unnecessary for my requirement (i dont want to save images in gallery). I probably just need the path to the cached image where it gets downloaded.

Can someone please explain how to get local file path of downloaded image file in React Native lingo ?

**EDIT**:

Not using Expo. And I want it to work with Android and iOS both.

Answer (score 1):

install [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs)

```
yarn add react-native-fs
```

and can get temporary path like this

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

const imageUrl = `http://www.example.com/abc.png`;
const imagePath = `${Platform.OS==="android"?"/storage/emulated/0/Download":RNFS.TemporaryDirectoryPath}/${((Math.random() * 1000) | 0)}.jpeg`;
RNFS.downloadFile({
        fromUrl: imageUrl,
        toFile: imagePath
    }).promise
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(imagePath);  //here you get temporary path
    })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e,"error");
      })
```

Comment: hey , Question is to download the image from firebase storage url to local storage

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install rn-fetch-blob
```

Follow these steps:

a) follow the installation instructions.

a2) if you want to manually install the package without using rnpm, go to their [wiki](https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob/wiki/Manually-Link-Package#index).

b) Finally, that's how I made it possible to download files within my app:

```
const { config, fs } = RNFetchBlob
let PictureDir = fs.dirs.PictureDir // this is the pictures directory. You can check the available directories in the wiki.
let options = {
  fileCache: true,
  addAndroidDownloads : {
    useDownloadManager : true, // setting it to true will use the device's native download manager and will be shown in the notification bar.
    notification : false,
    path:  PictureDir + "/me_"+Math.floor(date.getTime() + date.getSeconds() / 2), // this is the path where your downloaded file will live in
    description : 'Downloading image.'
  }
}
config(options).fetch('GET', "http://www.example.com/example.pdf").then((res) => {
  // do some magic here
})
```

#### OR

```
const { uri: localUri } = await FileSystem.downloadAsync(remoteUri, FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'name.ext');
```

Comment: The first option has Android specific key "addAndroidDownloads", does it work with android only or with iOS as well ? The second option works with expo only i guess. But i am not using expo.

Comment: For iOS it will ignore the settings in addAndroidDownloads and the file will be saved in the documents directory on the device, as that is the path that is given.

Comment: let PictureDir = Platform.OS === 'ios' ? fs.dirs.DocumentDir : fs.dirs.PictureDir;




Replace PictureDir to this line

Comment: Thanks @Ferin, it can solve the issue, but as i mentioned in the ques, i dont want to store the pic in the gallery. I just need location of cached image.

Comment: for iOS, its tricky to solves the issue, however in android it is easy and straight forward to implement and this code solves the issue for android.   Please upvote or accept my answer, it would be helpful.

Comment: I am waiting if some other relevant answer comes. otherwise i will accept yours.